# gameobject that rotate away from the facing direction of another game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to figure this out, but without success.

I have a AI that get to point X; facing that object, since I use transform.lookAt().

Now, I would like to turn the AI away, 180 degree, so it can face the same direction that the other agent is facing. I did try to add 180 to the transform once the AI get to destination but it doesn't work, sice the AI may arrive from any position, so the 180 degree rotation is not always the same as the direction in which the other agent is facing.

Is there a way to know or set, in which direction an object/AI/GameObject, is facing? Math wise, I believe it should be the vector3 related to when the object is imported in game, at 0.0.0 coordinates; although I can't really keep track of the orientation of every GO I have in the application; so I was hoping that there is some way to either set a direction, to which a GO is pointing at (even if it is not moving), or retrieve the orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [Transform.forward](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html)?

**Edited for completeness:**

Since transform.lookAt() is working for you currently, you can try this to face the target from any direction:

```
var lookPos = target.position - transform.position; 
lookPos.y = 0; 
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
```

and then add 180 degrees to the rotation

Comment: Yes, and for some objects that does not necessarly equal to the real forward direction. I believe the .forward on trasform component is based on the value 0 on the Z axis; which may or may not be equal to the face forwarding direction of the mesh. Before unify all the Z axis on all my mesh, I was evaluating other options before.